# How to compose multiple annotations for reuse if they don't have @Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, unmarshalling

I would like to reuse a bunch of the same annotations multiple times. But I can't just create another annotation by applying them because they lack `@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})`.
This annotation is inside Jakarta XML Binding (so can't be changed) and the goal is to get rid of the copy-paste.

I have an `operand`

```java
@XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "element1", type = Element1.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "element2", type = Element2.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "element3", type = Element3.class)
})
private MyOperand operand;
```

but another class has the same annotation on that field

```java
@XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "element1", type = Element1.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "element2", type = Element2.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "element3", type = Element3.class)
})
private List<MyOperand> operands;
```

I made a base class with that field and annotations for at least two classes which both have `List<MyOperand>`.

What is a better way?

Comment: This seems like a not great idea to use annotations.  Can you tell us your goal?  What will you use this annotation for?

Comment: This annotation is inside jakarta xml bind (so can't be changed) and the ultimate goal is to get rid of the copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

An annotation can take a list of arguments.  However the arguments are not dynamic and can't be added to or changed once defined

```
@interface ClassInfo{
   // Note use of array
   String[] myList();
}

@ClassInfo( myList = {"Larry", "Moe", "Curly"} )
public class MyClass {}
```

That list is static, you'd have to define subtypes of `MyClass` (or something) to make a different `myList` on each sub-type.

Comment: The problem is jakarta internally uses this `@XmlElement` annotation, so new annotations won't work. There is probably no way out of this, so thanks anyway